# Not redirecting to Login page with router.beforeEach VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, router

I need help, I've been trying to debug this for hours this is my the whole code for my routing:

I need this to automatically redirect to the login page and it won't redirect with using the router.beforeEach and there is no error on the console.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import store from "../store.js";
import Login from "@/views/Login.vue";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue"


Vue.use(Router);

let router = new Router({
  mode: "hash",
  linkActiveClass: "open active",
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/home",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      },

      children: [

      ]
    }, {
      path: "/login",
      name: "login",
      component: Login
    },

  ]
});
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      console.log(store.getters.isLoggedIn);
      if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
          next();
          return;
      }
      next("/login");
  } else {
      next();
  }
});
export default router;
```

Any help would do.

Comment: Does your `store.getters.isLoggedIn` return correct value ?

Comment: When are you setting the `isLoggedIn` ?